# How do I make a regex match for measurement units?

Tags: java, regex, units-of-measurement

I'm building a small Java library which has to match units in strings. For example, if I have "300000000 m/s^2", I want it to match against "m" and "s^2".

So far, I have tried most imaginable (by me) configurations resembling (I hope it's a good start)

```
"[[a-zA-Z]+[\\^[\\-]?[0-9]+]?]+"
```

To clarify, I need something that will match `letters[^[-]numbers]` (where [ ] denotes non obligatory parts). That means: letters, possibly followed by an exponent which is possibly negative.

I have studied regex a little bit, but I'm really not fluent, so any help will be greatly appreciated!

Thank you very much,

**EDIT:**
I have just tried the first 3 replies

```
String regex1 = "([a-zA-Z]+)(?:\\^(-?\\d+))?";
String regex2 = "[a-zA-Z]+(\\^-?[0-9]+)?";
String regex3 = "[a-zA-Z]+(?:\\^-?[0-9]+)?";
```

and it doesn't work... I know the code which tests the patterns work, because if I try something simple, like matching "[0-9]+" in "12345", it will match the whole string. So, I don't get what's still wrong. I'm trying with changing my brackets for parenthesis where needed at the moment...

**CODE USED TO TEST:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input = "30000 m/s^2";

//    String input = "35345";

    String regex1 = "([a-zA-Z]+)(?:\\^(-?\\d+))?";
    String regex2 = "[a-zA-Z]+(\\^-?[0-9]+)?";
    String regex3 = "[a-zA-Z]+(?:\\^-?[0-9]+)?";
    String regex10 = "[0-9]+";
    String regex = "([a-zA-Z]+)(?:\\^\\-?[0-9]+)?";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex3);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);

    if (matcher.matches()) {
        System.out.println("MATCHES");
        do {
            int start = matcher.start();
            int end = matcher.end();
//            System.out.println(start + " " + end);
            System.out.println(input.substring(start, end));
        } while (matcher.find());
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you post the code you are using to find the matches?

Comment: The problem is that you are not including / as an allowable character. You could choose to write it instead as ms^-2, and in general you can have multiple units, not just two.

Comment: I don't want it to match "m/s^2". I really need it to have separate matches for "m" and for "s^2". That's the reason for the do-while loop which is extracting every regex matches afterwards.

Comment: You need to use the `find` method, not the `matches` method.

Comment: I first check if it matches. If so, I read until it doesn't find anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're mixing the use of square brackets to denote character classes and curly brackets to group. Try this instead:

```
[a-zA-Z]+(\^-?[0-9]+)?
```

In many regular expression dialects you can use \d  to mean any digit instead of [0-9].

Answer (score 2):

```
([a-zA-Z]+)(?:\^(-?\d+))?
```

You don't need to use the character class `[`...`]` if you're matching a single character. `(`...`)` here is a capturing bracket for you to extract the unit and exponent later. `(?:`...`)` is non-capturing grouping.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
"[a-zA-Z]+(?:\\^-?[0-9]+)?"
```

Comment: Thanks, I have added, actually it was intentional, because I dont see - in the string to match